How can I get all Material UI color options as a type?
I wish to create a color picker using MaterialUI, similar to the one on this page:
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/color/
I'm using typescript and was hoping for some kind of built-in mapping.
I've made this: https://gist.github.com/ParadigmMalcontent/03d345ff5e8fd698a24fcb579a7440ae The idea is to do iterate through allColors.
...but I feel it's re-inventing some wheel that should have already been invented.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Come on, it's easy to understand this if you aren't a bot. I'm trying to see if there's something I can import from material ui or another library that provides the same functionality as my posted gist.

You can use a namespace import like import * as allColors from "@mui/material/colors";. If this meets your needs, I can write it as an answer — if not, what am I missing?

@jsejcksn Yeah, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

You can use a namespace import to create an object that will have as its properties all of the exports from the module — this includes the associated type information:
TS Playground
import * as allColors from "@mui/material/colors";

allColors.amber.A100
//              ^? (property) A100: "#ffe57f"

allColors.teal.A400
//             ^? (property) A400: "#1de9b6"

// …etc.

